# How to move code out of the main server.js file, but still use it when the app starts?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following:

```
// server.js

const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);

const connectedUsersSingular = {};
const connectedUsersGroupChat = {};

const socketOne = require("socket.io")(server, {
  path: "/socket-one",
});

const socketTwo = require("socket.io")(server, {
  path: "/socket-two",
});

socketOne.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("Connected to socket one")
}

socketTwo.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("Connected to socket two")
}
```

The problem with this is that both sockets have a lot of `socket.on("....")` listeners and my server.js file is getting huge.

I was thinking of making separate files for each socket and doing `module.exports = socketOne`, for example. But I won't have access to `server` variable this way, which I need in order to ensure that socket io is running on the same port as my app.

What can I do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a separate file but instead of `module.exports=socketOne` you can export a function that takes in the server variable instead

In socketOne.js

```
module.exports = (server) => {
   let socketOne = require("socket.io")(server, {
     path: "/socket-one",
   });
   socketOne.on("connection", socket => {
       console.log("Connected to socket one")
   })
   return socketOne;
}
```

Then in server.js,

```
const socketOne = require('./socketOne.js')(server);
```

Comment: How can I reference socketOne from the socketTwo module?